# Как безопасно, запустить программу через терминал? Python3

Tags: python-3.x, безопасность, shell, ос, subprocess

Как безопасно, запустить программу через терминал?
Пробовал:

```
import subprocess, os
filename="какойтофайл"
subprocess.run("gpg -c"+"'"+filename+"'" shell=True, check=True);
os.system("gpg -c"+"'"+filename+"'");
```

Всё время ругается "синтаксический анализатор" Bandit.
Говорит что в команде subprocess.run и os.system есть шел (shell) уязвимость. Как, именно, это устранить? Без этого не как нельзя выпускать продукт.

Comment: А зачем в первой строчке shell?

Answer (score 1):

Ну, я с bandit не работал, но из общих соображений могу предположить, что он агрится на то, что вы строчку команды собираете простой конкатенацией (что действительно часто оказывается плохой идеей).

Вместо этого лучше использовать синтаксис передачи аргументов команды отдельными элементами списка:

```
subprocess.run(["gpg", "-c", filename], shell=True, check=True)
```

PS: И не надо в питоне пихать точки с запятой после каждой строки.

Comment: Спасибо, но ошибок 9, теперь) Добавил логи.

Comment: @Notnaloginov Это уже другие ошибки, их нужно задавать отдельными вопросами. Данный сайт служит для накопления знаний, а если вы меняете вопрос на совсем другой уже после того, как на певый вопрос был дан полезный ответ, то это помешает другим людям найти этот ответ в будущем.